# golang bind generator for Java like `gomobile bind` for Android

Tags: java, go, binding, code-generation, backend

Is there an easier way to make Java binding for my go package? I want to use my small go package in backend builded on Java stack. The `gomobile bind` for Android is great tool, but i need the same thing just for Java.

Comment: is there some JNI feature in Android not compatible?

Comment: @JiangYD no, generated by `go bind` library is not compatible with Linux

Comment: gomobile use android features, like `Context` and `Log`. so better to use a   RPC for java-golang interaction, like protobuf.